# od emulation for directories

Tags: directory, od, dump, data

I was wondering why od(1) used to work in UNIX but doesn't work in GNU/Linux. There is a nice answer on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/317785). The next question is, are you aware of any tools that can emulate od behavior to support dumping directory data in GNU/Linux?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linux doesn't let you do a plain `read(dir_name, buffer, sizeof(buffer)` - it always returns -1 and puts EISDIR in `errno`.  This is probably rational, as not all filesystems have directories as files.  The commonly-used reiserfs does not, for example.

You can use the `open()` system call from a C program to get a file descriptor of a directory, but things like `readdir(3)` (from libc) call `getdents(2)` to actually retrieve directory entries.  There's probably code in each filesystem implementation to create `struct linux_dirent` from whatever (a file, a database, an on-disk B-tree) that filesystem uses to store directory entries.